# MariaDB Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I've been looking and looking at this code, but I can't find the problem. Can you help me to see it?

```
    $query = $dbc->prepare('UPDATE `division`
                            SET    `delete_flag` = 1,
                                   `updated_by`  = :user_id, 
                                   `updated_ip`  = :used_ip
                            WHERE  `division_id` = :division_id');
    $query->bindValue(':user_id',
                      $_SESSION['logged_in_person_id'],
                      PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':user_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(':division_id', $division_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
```

Why is the query execute giving me "HY093 SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"?

Comment: Can u add all the code please ?

Comment: Show us, where you set the `$division_id` and `$_SESSION['logged_in_person_id']`. Are you started the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have  `updated_ip`  = :used_ip and then in your  `$query->bindValue` you are using :user_ip', ?